# How do I replace value of Map if the key is present?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maps

I have this map:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
```

I'm trying to check if this map has a key called "Brian". If - and only if - it does, I want to replace the value with "Hello".

If I understand correctly the `computeIfPresent` method does exactly that, but it expects a **remappingFunction** as the second parameter, and I just want to put in a simple value.

I've tried this:

```
myMap.computeIfPresent("Brian", "Hello");
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<>();
myMap.put("Brian", "some");
System.out.println(myMap); // {Brian=some}
myMap.computeIfPresent("Brian", (key, value) -> "Hello"); // key is "Brian", value is "some", new value will be "Hello"
System.out.println(myMap); // {Brian=Hello}
```

remappingFunction is a BinaryFunction (which can be short-written with lambda), accepting found map entry key and its value. And expecting you to tell the program, how to compute new value.

Answer (score 6):

You can simply use [**Map::replace**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#replace-K-V-):

```
myMap.replace("Brain", "Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

Provide a function, whose result is the value you want and does not take into account the provided parameters:

```
myMap.computeIfPresent("Brian", (k, v) -> "Hello");
```

Answer (score 1):

You are passing a String as second parameter and it needs to be a BiFunction, try this:

```
myMap.computeIfPresent("Brian",(key,value)->"Hello");
```